# Altium: Copy parameter fields from one component to another during library creation

Tags: altium

I have creating library of components. These are the parameters fields for the first component that I have manually created:

[image]

Doing Add -> Parameter so many times for every component that I am creating into the schematic libraries is tedious. Is there a way to copy and paste the fields (with or without the values) into a different schematic symbol?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the component and edit the values?

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com

Comment: Yes, I did realise that I can copy paste and component in the schematic library and this will also copy all the parameters. I can then modify them.